# FetchAPI GraphQL / Gatsby throw error on frontend if null data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch, gatsby

I have set up a band site using Gatsby which utilises the Bandsintown API to get events whether they are upcoming or past events.

Displaying past events is fine, but I would like to display a message on the frontend if there are no upcoming events / no events i.e no data comes back from the fetch API call. I am not really sure how to go about this?
Currently I cannot even build the solution and get error in my console:

```
Cannot query field "allBandsInTownEvent" on type "Query"
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**gatsby-node.js** (local plugin)

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const queryString = require("query-string")

exports.sourceNodes = (
  { actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest },
  configOptions
) => {
  const { createNode } = actions
  delete configOptions.plugins

  const processEvent = event => {
    const nodeId = createNodeId(`bandsintown-event-${event.id}`)
    const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(event)
    const nodeData = Object.assign({}, event, {
      id: nodeId,
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `BandsInTownEvent`,
        content: nodeContent,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(event),
      },
    })
    return nodeData
  }

  const artist = configOptions.artist
  const app_id = configOptions.app_id
  const apiUrl = `https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${artist}/events?app_id=${app_id}&date=upcoming` //upcoming or past

  return fetch(apiUrl).then(response =>
    response.json().then(data => {
      if (Object.entries(data).length === 0) {
        return some kind of error? i.e document.querySelector(".no-shows").innerHTML = "No Shows on at the moment"
      }
      data.forEach(event => {
        const nodeData = processEvent(event)
        createNode(nodeData)
      })
    })
  )
}
```

**events.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import "./index.scss"

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query EventsQuery {
        allBandsInTownEvent(
          limit: 8
          sort: { fields: [datetime], order: DESC }
        ) {
          nodes {
            id
            venue {
              city
              country
              name
            }
            artist {
              id
              facebook_page_url
              image_url
              name
            }
            datetime(formatString: "ddd, MMM DD YYYY")
            url
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <div className="Events">
        <div className="event-header">Tour Dates</div>
        <div className="event-content">
          {data.allBandsInTownEvent.nodes.map(node => (
              <div className="event-item" key={node.id}>
                <div className="event-details">
                  <div className="event-datetime">{node.datetime}</div>
                  <div className="event-name">{node.venue.name}</div>
                  <div className="event-venue">
                    <div className="city">{node.venue.city}</div>
                    <div className="region">{node.venue.region}</div>
                    <div className="country">{node.venue.country}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="event-cta">
                  <a
                    href={node.url}
                    rel="noreferrer"
                    target="_blank"
                    title={node.title}
                  >
                    Tickets
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  />
)
```

Comment: ... but you know it's build/deploy time fetching ... will show outdated data if not rebuild/redeployed on every change ... you can mix it (static site/contents) with run time fetching ... read gatsby docs

Comment: Ah yes thank you, doh totally missed that, I have built one other site using gatsby/contentful and have a webhook setup to rebuild the solution on content change.
Will look into this cheers

Comment: I don't work with gatsby these days but it looks like no `createContentDigest` (**probably required** to 'register' type in 'Query') called at all ... I would try ... if no data insert [and remove] some dummy event (by calling `processEvent`)?